# Issue with setting up a local subversion repository

Tags: svn, windows-7

I went through this [tutorial](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html) to setup subversion on my windows 7 laptop, which I did successfully.  However, I tried to add in the subclipse client plugin for Eclipse Indigo and ran into an issue where I couldn't connect to the repository.

So, I uninstalled everything and then tried to reinstall it again.  I used "sc delete svnserver and sc delete SVNService" to delete the windows service as part of the uninstall process.

I got to the point where I ran this create server command successfully:
sc create svnserver binpath= "c:\svn\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r c:\svn\repository"
displayname= "Subversion" depend= Tcpip start= auto

However, now I'm getting this error when I try to start the server:  C:>net start svnserver **System error 2 has occurred** either from the command line or from trying to start it from the windows service console.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Aftermath: I think the underlying issue was how to clean everything up after a failed install, but going to a different svn version address that.

Comment: It's really mu-uch easier to install VisualSVN Server on your laptop than to mess with the manual setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to delete all the svn files on my hard drive, deleting subclipse, tortise, silksvn, and then reinstalling VisualSVN using the instructions [here](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2009/10/setting-up-eclipse-subclipse-and-visual.html).

I installed subclipse first, then installed VisualSVN, which worked for me and avoided all the configuration steps I had to do with other SVN packages that were referenced in the original tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

According to this link a system error 2 error is a file not found error. Verify your path to the repository. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

This is what my server create statement looks like

```
sc create svnserve binpath= "\"C:\svn\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -r C:\svn\fruvyRepository" displayname= "Subversion Server" depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

Notice the binpath. I had to character escape the quotes around my path.

Comment: I tried to escaping the quotes, but it didn't make any difference.